# How to skip a specific scenario having unique tag from TestNG runner

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have feature file with lots of scenarios, which run on multiple countries. To run on different countries I have created different TestNG runner classes. 
Here my question is how can I skip a scenario to run from a specific runner file. I am running scenario's using a feature level tag.

For Example : 
Feature file is having `@regression` tag and I am using this tag in 
all runner classes to across the countries. Since data issue for some 
countries I want skip some scenario for some countries.(I am using TestNG 
runner). I have seen that in JUnit runner you can use not to skip but the 
same is not working in TestNG runner.

I tried below :

```
@CucumberOptions(
plugin = "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:", 
monochrome = true, 
features = "src/features/Cart", 
tags = { "@regression and not @invalid"}

    @regression
    Feature: Validate login functionality for all countries

    @valid
      Scenario Outline: login with valid user access
        Given site launched
          And user enters "<username>"
          And user enters "<password>"
         When user clicks Sign In button
         Then display user home page

        Examples: 
          | username | password | 
          | xyz      | xyz123   | 
          | abc      | abc123   | 

      @invalid
      Scenario Outline: login with invalid user access
        Given site launched
          And user enters "<username>"
          And user enters "<password>"
         When user clicks Sign In button
         Then display user home page

        Examples: 
          | username | password | 
          | xyz      | xyz123   | 
          | abc      | abc123   |
```

Below is my runner class file :

```
    package runner;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

    import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
    import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
    import utils.ConfigManagement;
    import utils.ExcelSheetManager;
    import utils.ExtentReportUtills;

    @CucumberOptions(plugin = "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:",
    monochrome = true, features = "src/features/Cart", tags = { "@regression and not @invalid"},

            format = { "html:cucumber-html-reports1",
                    "json:cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json" }, dryRun = false, glue = "steps")
    public class EU_IR_EN extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

        public static Map<String, String> configDetails = new HashMap<>();

        @BeforeClass
        public static void setup() throws Exception {

            Map<String, String> SheetData = new HashMap<>();
            String key = "Cart";
            SheetData.put("SHEETNAME", key);
            configDetails = ConfigManagement.GetConfigDetailsForRCL(key);
            SheetData.putAll(configDetails);
            System.out.println("map at class level of runner1" + SheetData);
            ExcelSheetManager.setData(SheetData);
            System.out.println("first statement");
        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void prepareReport() throws Exception {
            ExtentReportUtills.UpdateExtentReport();
        }
    }
```

Below is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>cucumberTest</groupId>
<artifactId>FSCartUIAutomation</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For excel file handling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>hindsighttesting.release</id>
        <name>Hindsight Software Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.hindsightsoftware.com/public-maven</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <plugins>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.hindsighttesting.behave</groupId>
            <artifactId>behave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install6</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>features</goal>
                    </goals>

                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>GFSCart.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                <forkCount>4</forkCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>

                <!-- <source>${jdk.level}</source> <target>${jdk.level}</target> -->

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]

Comment: Can u add a sample feature file tht u looking to skip with tag info?

Comment: @grasshopper : I have added sample feature file in main question please have a look. I want to use at_regression tag to run scenarios but mean while i want to ignore or skip at_invalid scenario from execution when I use at_regression

Comment: What u r doing is correct. Are u getting error or it is not skipping? What happens when u used 'valid'tag only?

Comment: In console I am seeing this -- None of the features at [src/features/Cart] matched the filters: [@regression and not @invalid]

Comment: even with Junit is not working... None of the features at [src/features/Cart] matched the filters: [@regression and not @invalid]

0 Scenarios
0 Steps

Comment: Updated summary with runner file.

Comment: Wht is the cucumber version?

Comment: i tried same combo in my machine, but i see the tests are triggered correctly, can you pls share your pom.xml?. Also share your project structure, i am just speculating path of your feature files is incorrect... Are they located under src/features/Cart?

Comment: @mani : It is working fine when i runner file without 'not'. So path of feature is correct.

Comment: @Grasshopper : added pom.xml to summary.

Comment: @sam u are using pretty old version. For versions before 2.0.0 this tag filter will not work. Try this tags= { "@regression","~@invalid"}

Comment: @Grasshopper : Thank you, the above solution worked for me. However I tried to upgrade my cucumber(cucumber-java to 4.2.0) version to latest version but I am getting an error in runner file. Error : The attribute format is undefined for the annotation type CucumberOptions. Could you please tell what other dependencies I have to update in pom.xlm pasted above in order to use latest version and its features. (It would be great you if you update my pom.xml with latest versions to be used.)

Comment: Remove all dependencies with cucumber in them from pom. Add the cucumber-java dependency. If u are using java8 then add cucumber-java8 dependency instead.Add testng jar and cucumber-testng jar. That is all that is required. Use plugins option instead of format as it has been removed from CucumberOptions annotation

Comment: @Grasshopper : I updated my pox.xml with latest versions and format to option but still I am getting the same error in runner file.The attribute opton is undefined for the annotation type CucumberOptions. Do I need to update anything in runner file. ?

Comment: U need to use word 'plugins' instead of 'format'. plugins = { "html:cucumber-html-reports1",                     "json:cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json" }

Comment: Grasshopper : When I tried plugins I am getting same error and when i change it plugin it is saying 'Duplicate attribute plugin in annotation @CucumberOptions'. Added error screenshot.

Comment: Ooops It is 'plugin' not the plural. Just add the extent plugin to the existing options. plugin = { "html:cucumber-html-reports1",                     "json:cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json", "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tags to run / skip specific scenarios.

From the [docs](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#ignoring-a-subset-of-scenarios):
You can tell Cucumber to ignore scenarios with a particular tag:

Using JUnit runner class:

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = "not @smoke")
class RunCucumberTest {}
```